# Using Spring Boot without the parent POM doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying the simple sample from the SpringBoot QuickStart (http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start). 
Using the spring-boot-starter-parent as the parent is working fine. I can run the sample without any problems.
But I absolutely need to use my own parent pom. So I read the documentation : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

I tried it. It compiled fine. But crashes at run time.
Here is my configuration.
In my parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    ....
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    ....
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when I run the application, I get this:

```
    2014-08-11 12:50:29.275 ERROR 28474 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: class com.imetrik.oaas.tool.application.springboottest.SampleController.SampleController
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:169)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.isAnnotated(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.isAnnotated(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:620)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at com.imetrik.oaas.tool.application.springboottest.SampleController.SampleController.main(SampleController.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3178)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3158)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:195)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:165)
    ... 18 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: class com.imetrik.oaas.tool.application.springboottest.SampleController.SampleController
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:169)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.isAnnotated(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.isAnnotated(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:620)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at com.imetrik.oaas.tool.application.springboottest.SampleController.SampleController.main(SampleController.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3178)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3158)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:195)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:165)
    ... 18 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no clue how to solve this. I tried putting the dependencyManagement directly in my pom (not in the parent). Same result.
I did search here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I cannot find a single working example.
We are using Maven 3.0.4 and Java 1.7U51

Comment: You need to look at the effective POM to check the final dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my parent pom was dependent on Spring 3.2.5.
And I find out that Spring-Boot 1.5.x needs at least Spring 4.
This is not clearly defined on the Spring-Boot page.

Comment: This doesn't work now (for me at least for Springboot 2.0.5) if I don't explicitly denote in the `executions` tag that the plugin must run in `repackage` phase.

Answer (score 12):

I may be late but I am sure it will be helpful to everyone who wants to run **SpringBoot without inheriting from parent**. It was very frustrating to figure the following but it finally it worked for me!

Basically,

1. Intellij maven auto-import was turned off. Enabled it.
2. I have to add spring-boot dependencies manually. i.e if you just inherit spring-boot as parent, you will be given a default set of dependencies to work on. But when you don't inherit you have to declare those dependencies manually in pom.xml
3. If you observe pom.xml, "spring-boot-dependencies" has to be in its own `<dependencyManagement>` tag. If you combine all of the dependencies in a single `<dependencies>`, then references are lost in the code!
4. See the following example:

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Chethan</artifactId>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>myspringbootwithoutparent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> </project>
```

ApplicationWithoutParentPom.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Created by chethanshankar on 10/18/16.
 */
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ApplicationWithoutParentPom {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World without SPRING BOOT AS PARENT!!!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationWithoutParentPom.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Errors

##### java: error: release version 5 not supported

When compiling the project you may get this error

```
java: error: release version 5 not supported

Module todolist SDK 17 does not support source version 1.5. 
Possible solutions:
- Downgrade Project SDK in settings to 1.5 or compatible. Open project settings.
- Upgrade language version in Maven build file to 17. Update pom.xml and reload the project.
```

You can fix by adding inside the `<properties>` the maven compiler version, in my case for Java 17

```xml
 <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: you must specify the version of spring in the maven properties, without it, it doesn't work.
`<spring.version>a_version_of_spring</spring.version>`

Comment: i did it in that way, its works with dependecies, but ofc do not works with plugins. is there an easy way to "import" or i have to copy&paste pluginManagement from spirng-boot-parent ?